# Как заполнить по умолчанию динамический массив?

Tags: массивы, c

Приветствую господа! Есть некая структура **Film** и 2 массива: **test** и **VideoArr** (статичный и динамичный). Заполнить по умолчанию test можно без проблем. А вот как заполнить по умолчанию динамический массив VideoArr?

Пробовал такой вариант:

```
//VideoArr[0].genre="test"; 
//VideoArr[0].rating=7.3;
//VideoArr[0].price=58.5;
```

Числовые значения записываются нормально, а вот если в жанр записывать "test" компилятор ругается.

От сюда вопрос, как будет наиболее правильно заполнить динамический массив строками по умолчанию?

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct Film
    {
        char name[50];
        char producer[50];
        char genre[30];
        float rating;
        float price;
    };
    int size=10;
    Film test[10]={{"mars", "petia", "fantastika" ,11.5,5},{"terminator", "cameron", "fantastika" ,10.1,5}};
    Film *VideoArr= new Film[size];
...
```

Comment: Тоже интересно, потому что я всегда заполнял {'t','e','s','t'}, что есть костылище.

Comment: Если в коде хочется написать 

   char test[20];
   
   test = "my string";

то нужно писать так

   char test[20];
   
   strcpy(test, "my string");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы используете статический инициализатор. В вашем случае (Си-стиль) можно обращаться непосредственно к полям. Возможно, есть смысл написать отдельную функцию CreateFilm():

```
const int size=10;
Film **ptrTest = new *ptrTest[size];
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    CreateAndInitFilm(&ptrTest[i]);
}   
...
// Использование
...
for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    ReleaseFilm(&ptrTest[i]);
}  
delete [] ptrTest;
```

---

```
void CreateAndInitFilm(Film **outPtr)
{
    (*outPtr) = new Film;
    strcpy((*outPtr)->name,"mars");
    strcpy((*outPtr)->producer,"petia");
    strcpy((*outPtr)->genre,"fantastika");
    (*outPtr)->rating   = 11.5;
    (*outPtr)->price    = 5;
}

void ReleaseFilm(Film **outPtr)
{
    delete (*outPtr);
    (*outPtr) = nullptr;
}
```

В случае с С++ стоило бы воспользоваться конструктором по умолчанию.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что в новом стандарте С появилось ключевое слово new ? и конструкции вида `outPtr->producer = "petia";` отрабатывают?

Comment: у топикстартера тоже присутствует new в коде, хотя помечено меткой "С".

Comment: @KoVadim
Конечно! Даже delete с iostream есть. Не ломайте нам идиллию!)

На счет присваивания строковой константы я погорячился, сейчас поправлю. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вы путаете инициализацию с присваиванием. Нельзя напрямую присвоить в char[] строку через двойные кавычки вот почему:

```
char test[]="LOL"; //<- инициализация
test = "NEW LOL";//нельзя присваивать строковый литерал указателю, так как test - указатель на первый символ, а сама строка - массив символов.
```

В Вашем случае:

```
Film test[10]={{...}}//инициализация, где с фигурных скобок идек блок инициализаторов, потому прекрасно работает
```

Чтобы присвоить char * строку в двойных кавычках (строковый литерал) используйте функцию из string.h - strcpy или её модификации